# threading code.InteractiveInterpreter and getting output as commands are executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to create a console in a GUI, pyqt5, and I am having trouble getting the output from the InteractiveInterpreter. I do not know if my InteractiveInterpreter  is threaded properly or what. when I run the code below (without trying to capture the output ) the code is printed sequentially but I would expect to have an output to be something like this:

```
hi
0 interpreter
0 main
1 interpreter
1 main
2 interpreter
2 main
3 interpreter
4 interpreter
```

instead I get this:

```
hi
0 interpreter
1 interpreter
2 interpreter
3 interpreter
4 interpreter
0 main
1 main
2 main
```

code:

```
import code
import threading
from time import sleep 
import sys
    

class IC(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, context=None):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      
      self.Console = code.InteractiveInterpreter(context)

    def push(self, x, sym=''):
        return self.Console.runsource(x,sym)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a=IC()
    a.start()
    a.push("print('hi')")
    a.push("from time import sleep")
    a.push("for i in range(5):\n\t print(i,'interpreter')\n\t sleep(1)\n")

    for i in range(3):
        print(i, 'main')
        sleep(1)
```

Update:
I the code is now running like I expect however I am unable to catch print statements. I tried using contxtlib but I am getting the text as it is printing, but in one large chunck. How can I capture the print statements as they come, latter I will pass these strings to a qtextedit.

this is the code as I'm using now:

```html
import code
import threading, queue
from time import sleep 
import sys

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


class IC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.On = True
        self.qin = queue.Queue()
        self.qout = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.runtime, daemon=True).start()

    def push(self, x):
        self.qin.put(x)

    def runtime(self):
        self.Console = code.InteractiveInterpreter()
        while self.On:
            f = io.StringIO()
            with redirect_stdout(f):
                if self.qin.qsize()>0:
                    self.Console.runsource(self.qin.get())
            if f.getvalue():
                print("caught:", f.getvalue())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a=IC()
    a.push("print('hi')")
    a.push("from time import sleep")
    a.push("for i in range(5):\n\t print(i,'interpreter')\n\t sleep(2)\n")

    for i in range(3):
        print(i, 'main')
        sleep(1.5)
```

and this is the output I'm getting, in idle. The first two lines are what I want/expect, but when I enter the for loop I have to wait for it to get out for me to get the results, instead of getting each print statement individually.

```html
caught: 0 main

caught: hi

>>> caught: 0 interpreter
1 main
1 interpreter
2 main
2 interpreter
3 interpreter
4 interpreter
```

Comment: You're not actually doing anything in the thread.

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary (and wrong) code snippet tags. Also try to make your code as minimal as possible, avoiding repeating code and functions or comments that are not really important for your issue, which, as already pointed out, is missing an important part of the problem: what you're using threading for, since right now it's doing nothing: provide an example that is *both* [minimal *and* reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante, sorry I added the tags that are involved in my problem. I deleted the additional code as well

Comment: @user169808 with "tags" I meant the HTML tags (`<!-- begin snippet: ... -->`), which you unfortunately just restored after another user correctly removed them. Read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), and remember that the "language" tag must reflect the actual language used (in your case, python, not html).

Answer (score 0):

**@user2357112supportsMonica** is correct. You create a thread and then start the thread but the thread isn't doing anything. The interactive interpreter was initialized in the thread class and you added a function to the thread class but all the calls you do are from the main thread and run on the main thread.

The only time code is run inside the thread you created is when the code is in the target function.

I would suggest you review threading in the python documentation and specifically look at how to set the target of a thread and how to loop in the thread to keep it alive and working. Then also you may need to look into `Queues` for passing data to the new thread.

Comment: thanks I rewrote the class and now this part is working like I expect

Comment: Hope I was able to help. If my answer did help please mark it as the accepted answer so that this question can be closed.